# Can you use the Raspberry Pi 4 B to control 1 or more Raspberry Pi Zero's?

Tags: pi-zero, server, raspbian-lite, minecraft, pi-4

My project is going to use Pi 4 to connect to 1 or 2 Pi Zeros. I would want the Pi 4 to control the Pi Zeros. Would that work? Also I am going to connect the Pi 4 to the Ethernet. Also would the Pi 4 link the Pi Zero to the internet? I will probaly use this for a Minecraft server with BungeeCord. I would prefer Raspbian Lite to use.

Any suggestions or ideas would be great.

Comment: `to control the Pi Zero` - in what way?

Comment: Like have full access

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Note that we are not a discussion style forum and open ended invitations to brainstorm are not appropriate to the format. Maybe you should have a look at the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your raspberries will be connected to the same network, so in fact you could use a master to drive the other one distributing tasks.

This could be achieved by *SSH* communications.
You should also take a look and force IP to your raspberries on your internet provider box.
I mean you can configure your internet router, to give your raspberries fixed IP, which will ne necessary if your want your raspberry network to be reboot resistant.
You may find theses configurations under **DHCP Server** (on your router).

Anyway, what you are trying to achieve may be close to what is called *Raspberry cluster*, you will encounter the same issues so take a look at some tutorials

[Raspberry cluster tutorial](https://medium.com/@glmdev/building-a-raspberry-pi-cluster-784f0df9afbd)